# Cross Correlation in Java (Android) Using FFT (Frequency Domain Convolution / Correlation)

Tags: fft, cross-correlation, java, reference-implementation

I want to implement cross-correlation with the start-symbol and the signal using FFT.

I zero-pad both signals to length N = x.len + y.len -1
Using the convolution theorem:

```
        corr(x, y) = IFFT( FFT(x_padded) .* conj(FFT(y_padded)))
```

Do you have any good library recommendations I could use to compute both the FFT and IFFT?
I am running this on an Android app and efficiency is important.

Moreover, the best correlation is the highest peak in the array of the result. How does the index k of the array corr(x,y) relate to x? Does that mean the best alignment is when y lags k samples behind x?

Comment: Kiss is a pretty good and easy to use library written in c or c++(can't remember). I'm not aware of  any Java FFT libraries and performance might be an issue if you choose a Java library (https://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/reviews?source=navbar).

Comment: There appears to be a Java implementation of the FFT [here.](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/~ronw/code/MEAPsoft/doc/html/FFT_8java-source.html) [Doug L. Jones](https://ece.illinois.edu/directory/profile/dl-jones) seems to have originated it, which means it's probably kosher.

Answer (score 0):

If index k refer to the highest correlation coeffitient and let n be the length of each x and y, so would n-k be the lag for y at maxima of the correlation function.

For some applications I prefer the cosine similarity instead of plain correlation, but which is less efficient in calculation.